# ColdFusion/Java - Class not found: org.apache.ws.security.WSConstants

Tags: java, coldfusion

The following code throws an error "Class not found: org.apache.ws.security.WSConstants"

```
<cfset variables.WSConstantsObj = CreateObject("Java","org.apache.ws.security.WSConstants")>
```

I'm not sure if this should just work out of the box or whether there is something else I need to do to instantiate this java object.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I appear to have figured it out.
Needed a couple of other jar files loaded first, in my particular instance.

```
variables.paths = arrayNew(1);
variables.paths[1] = getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath()) & "lib\wss4j-1.5.8.jar";
variables.paths[2] = getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath()) & "lib\xmlsec-1.4.2.jar";
variables.loader = createObject("component","lib.javaloader.JavaLoader").init(loadPaths=variables.paths,loadColdFusionClassPath=true);
variables.WSConstantsObj = loader.create("org.apache.ws.security.WSConstants");
```